# Lombok @Builder with Java 8 Lambda Builder Pattern

Tags: java, lambda, lombok

I am trying to use Lombok with the Java 8 Lambda builder pattern introduced [here](https://medium.com/beingprofessional/think-functional-advanced-builder-pattern-using-lambda-284714b85ed5).

POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RestResponse<T> {
  @Getter @Setter @Builder.Default private Boolean success = true;
  @Getter @Setter @NonNull private T data;

  public static class RestResponseBuilder<T> {
    public RestResponseBuilder<T> with(Consumer<RestResponseBuilder<T>> builderFunction) {
      builderFunction.accept(this);
      return this;
    }

    public RestResponse<T> createRestResponse() {
      return new RestResponse<T>(success, data);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```java
  @GetMapping(value = "/testLambdaBuilder", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public RestResponse<String> testEndpointLambdaBuilder() {
    return new RestResponseBuilder<String>().with($ -> $.data = "helloWorld").createRestResponse();
  }
```

Lombok seems to create a package level constructor for the builder. Is there a way to change it to public? The error I'm getting is:

> The constructor RestResponse.RestResponseBuilder() is not visible

Comment: Provide us the full code please.

Answer (score 0):

Because the builder class already partially exists, Lombok will simply inject the correct fields into your `RestResponseBuilder`. From [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) (emphasis mine):

> Each listed generated element will be silently skipped if that element
>   already exists (disregarding parameter counts and looking only at
>   names). This includes the builder itself: **If that class already
>   exists, lombok will simply start injecting fields and methods inside
>   this already existing class, unless of course the fields / methods to
>   be injected already exist.**

So if you want the field to have public visibility in the builder class then you just need to declare it there and Lombok will respect it:

```
public static class RestResponseBuilder<T> {
    public T data;

    public RestResponseBuilder<T> with(Consumer<RestResponseBuilder<T>> builderFunction) {
        builderFunction.accept(this);
        return this;
    }

    public RestResponse<T> createRestResponse() {
        return new RestResponse<T>(success, data);
    }
}
```

All of this said, your `with` method seems quite strange. You can just do this:

```
return new RestResponse.RestResponseBuilder<String>().data("helloWorld").createRestResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in using the lambda builder pattern in combination with Lombok?

As I understand it, using the lambda builder pattern saves you from adding the setter methods in your builder (and implementing it correctly) every time you add a new variable to your pojo / value object.

But if you already use Lombok to generate your builder, all of the builder code is already generated. So there is no need to write the methods yourself. Lombok also updates the builder code whenever you change your pojo.

So I would recommend: either use Lombok and go with the default builder that gets generated OR write your builder yourself and use the lambda builder pattern to save you from writing and maintaining too many methods.